# Xp SP3 - Non-Functioning

Tags: windows-xp, browser, sp3

Ok Here is a crazy problem, I have a HP dv6000 Laptop that can no longer hold a charge, so I hooked it up to my TV, bought a wireless mouse and keyboard and configured xp to run with the lid closed, It has medium to heavy usage mainly just streaming from sites like Netfilx, Hulu, ABC, etc. And playing movies I ripped of dvd. It ran fine for a while but recently it has been having some weird problems:

#### Problem one:

I used to use firefox but now when run it I can type but as soon as I click something it just shuts down, completely, I can't even close it unless I use taskmanager to do it. So I went and got google chrome which is better but still hit or miss, but never completely shuts down, I just can't click anything or type anything, or sometimes I just can't type anything or vice versa. Also when I open a new tab, and try to move back to my old one, it automatically closes the old tab when I click on it.

#### Problem two:

When using the internet I can't use any other application or anything windows (ie. Windows explorer) until I force quit all browsers with taskmanger. The reason I can't run anything is because I can't click on it.

#### Problem three:

When I try to play a movie (with vlc) Once it starts playing I can't click on anything, but I can use hotkeys, and once it stops everything is fine again.

Well I hope somebody knows whats going on because I have no clue, If you need clarification or more info on something I would be happy to provide it...

Answer (score 1):

It may be an overheating problem. Not all laptops like to be run for hours or days on end with the lid closed, especially with the constant disk usage required for streaming media. Try turning it off for a day or so, if you haven't already. If the battery is still installed, take it out--it's not doing anything but generating heat. Try buying a laptop cooling pad and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Very true. Be sure you've set Windows power configuration (in your control panel) to High Power as well - laptops are meant to be mobile, and it could be scaling your processor back (ie, slowing it down) to cool down.

Answer (score 0):

Recently took it out to install windows 7 on it and realized that the whole problem was the mouse lol.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have a [virus](http://www.free-av.com/en/trialpay_download/1/avira_antivir_personal__free_antivirus.html) or a [malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php)

The easiest and fast way is (probably) to reinstall windows.